# ¿Cómo obtener los números en posición par dentro de un array y ordenarlo ascendentemente?

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

Tengo esta función la cual necesito que solo me muestre cada miembro par del `array`.
Luego debo ordenarla de forma creciente, pero no entiendo muy bien cómo terminarlo.

Aquí he hecho que se me muestren los pares

```js
function myarray(arr) {
  let arreglo = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    arreglo.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return arreglo;
}
console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8, 6]));
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort

Comment: ¿Cuando dices que quieres los miembros pares te refieres a que tengan indice par o valor par?. Saludos.

Comment: eso, no muestra los pares.. muestra los que estan en un indice par...

Comment: si, que me muestre los de indice 0,2,4,6...

Comment: Los arrays tienen una serie de métodos; entre ellos uno que es array.sort() Busca documentación, son cosas que ya están implementadas basta con buscar un poco.

Answer (score 2):

Sólo te falta ordenar el resultado.

Pides que te devuelva los índices pares, eso ya lo hace tu función, ahora sólo debes devolverlos ordenados de forma creciente. Te puedes apoyar en el método [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) de los tipo [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array).

Basta con sustituir tu sentencia `return` actual:

```
return arreglo;
```

Por esta otra: (para ordenar de forma creciente).

```
return arreglo.sort((a, b) => { return a - b;});
```

Ejemplo (creciente):

```js
function myarray(arr) {
  let arreglo = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    arreglo.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return arreglo.sort((a, b) => { return a - b;});
}
console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8, 6]));
```

Si lo deseas de forma decreciente, basta con variar la resta:

```
return arreglo.sort((a, b) => { return b - a;});
```

Ejemplo (decreciente):

```js
function myarray(arr) {
  let arreglo = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    arreglo.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return arreglo.sort((a, b) => { return b - a;});
}
console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8, 6]));
```

**A [petición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384735/tengo-una-duda-con-un-array/384747?noredirect=1#comment689295_384747) de @JackNavaRow, usando un estilo *one-liner***

Todo se puede resumir a una simple linea si se combinan las poderosas herramientas de programación funcional que provee Javascript.

En este caso usaré el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) de los tipo `Array`, que devuelve un nuevo `Array` con los elementos que cumplan la condición de filtro.

La línea sería simplemente esta:

```
return arr.filter(element => { return arr.indexOf(element) % 2 === 0 }).sort((a, b) => {return a - b});
```

Ejemplo:

```js
function myarray(arr) {
  return arr.filter(element => { return arr.indexOf(element) % 2 === 0 }).sort((a, b) => {return a - b});
}
console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8, 6]));
```

Básicamente estoy filtrando los elementos del `Array` y devuelvo sólo aquellos cuyo índice sea par. Como se observa paso como argumento al método `filter` el elemento que se está iterando, y verifico si su índice en el `Array` es par. El índice lo obtengo con [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf).

También podría usar el argumento de índice, y hacer la función de otra forma.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function myarray(arr) {
  return arr.filter((element, index) => { return (index % 2 === 0);}).sort((a, b) => {return a - b});
}
console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8, 6]));
```

Ambas formas son válidas y satisfacen a los *one-liners*. ;)

Comment: y porque no ´return arr.sort()´esa recorrida del for no es necesaria y tampoco la funcion

Comment: Porque de esa forma se ve una implementación de la función de ordenamiento, que muchas veces se omite y se deja que `sort()` lo haga por defecto. Además da la posibilidad de mostrar el caso de ordenamiento decreciente. Para este caso en particular, el OP ya había obtenido la solución parcial de obtener los elementos en posiciones pares, faltaba sólo el ordenamiento. Tal vez puede hacerse en una sola linea combinando `filter` y `sort`, por lo cual lo añadiré a mi respuesta. @JackNavaRow *There's a boat, Jack*.

Comment: mi pregunta era el for ese al inicio pero ya lo entendi

Answer (score 1):

con .sort() lo ordenas.

```js
function myarray(arr) {
      let arreglo = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        arreglo.push(arr[i]);
      }
      return arreglo.sort();
    }
    console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8, 6]));
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el OP mencionó que se refiere a los índices par y no a los valores. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Este método te va insertando de forma ordenada los elementos que deseas:

```
 function myarray(arr) {
        let arreglo = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
            arreglo.push(arr[i]);
            for (let j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
                var temp = arreglo[j];
                if (arreglo[j] < arreglo[j - 1]) {
                    arreglo[j] = arreglo[j - 1];
                    arreglo[j - 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return arreglo;
    }
    console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8,6]));
```

Si lo que deseas, en lugar de las posiciones pares que fue lo que pusiste en el comentario, son los números pares:

```
function myarray(arr) {
        let arreglo = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                arreglo.push(arr[i]);
                for (let j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
                    var temp = arreglo[j];
                    if (arreglo[j] < arreglo[j - 1]) {
                        arreglo[j] = arreglo[j - 1];
                        arreglo[j - 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return arreglo;
    }
    console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8,
        6
    ]));
```

Utilizando sort para los elementos de las posiciones pares:

```
 function myarray(arr) {
        let arreglo = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
            arreglo.push(arr[i]);
        }
        arreglo.sort();
        return arreglo;
    }
    console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8,
        6
    ]));
```

Utilizando sort para los elementos pares:

```
function myarray(arr) {
        let arreglo = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                arreglo.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        arreglo.sort();
        return arreglo;
    }
    console.log(myarray([3, 4, 67, 8,
        6
    ]));
```